# How to remove leading masked elements in a numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

How to remove leading masked elements from a numpy array.
for example the masked array of [2 x 5] below:

```
m_arr = [[- - 1 - 1]
     [1 - - 1 1]]
```

output of removing leading masked element would be

```
m_arr = [[1 - 1]
     [1 - - 1 1]]
```

I tried using compressed in list comprehension as

```
[m.compressed.tolist() for m in m_arr]
```

But haven't got a solution by even doing np.apply_along_axis!!

Comment: I don't think masked arrays help you.  Use the `data` and `mask` separately, row by row.

Comment: You cannot have a non-rectangular array in numpy as you posted for your desired output. You would need to use a different data structure like lists for it.

Comment: If you are OK with having a 1D array and another array of indices where to split it, this is not too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, make the masked array:

```
In [96]: m_arr=np.ma.MaskedArray(np.arange(10).reshape(2,5),np.array([[1,1,0,1,0
    ...: ],[0,1,1,0,0]]))
In [97]: m_arr
Out[97]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[--, --, 2, --, 4],
        [5, --, --, 8, 9]],
  mask=[[ True,  True, False,  True, False],
        [False,  True,  True, False, False]],
  fill_value=999999)
```

Look at the 1d array attributes when we iterate:

```
In [99]: [(m.data,m.mask) for m in m_arr]
Out[99]: 
[(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([ True,  True, False,  True, False])),
 (array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([False,  True,  True, False, False]))]
```

Explore one mask:

```
In [100]: m_arr[0].mask
Out[100]: array([ True,  True, False,  True, False])
In [101]: np.logical_and.accumulate(m_arr[0].mask)
Out[101]: array([ True,  True, False, False, False])
In [104]: m_arr[0][~_101]
Out[104]: 
masked_array(data=[2, --, 4],
             mask=[False,  True, False],
       fill_value=999999)
```

wrap that in function:

```
In [109]: def foo(m):
     ...:     mm = m.mask
     ...:     mm = ~np.logical_and.accumulate(mm)
     ...:     return m[mm]
     ...:
```

and apply it row by row:

```
In [110]: [foo(m) for m in m_arr]
Out[110]: 
[masked_array(data=[2, --, 4],
              mask=[False,  True, False],
        fill_value=999999),
 masked_array(data=[5, --, --, 8, 9],
              mask=[False,  True,  True, False, False],
        fill_value=999999)]
```

====

In a followup question you tried to apply the `logical_and` to the whole array (as opposed to row by row):

```
In [132]: np.logical_and.accumulate(m_arr.mask)
Out[132]: 
array([[ True,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False]])
```

Correct application - by row:

```
In [133]: np.logical_and.accumulate(m_arr.mask, axis=1)
Out[133]: 
array([[ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]])
```

Using a boolean mask **always** flattens the result.  We've already made it clear that the result can't be 2d - at least not in a general case where the number of true values per row differ.

```
In [134]: m_arr[~_]
Out[134]: 
masked_array(data=[2, --, 4, 5, --, --, 8, 9],
             mask=[False,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False, False],
       fill_value=999999)
```

Comment: Yours is faster until the arrays become very large. I'm guessing the overhead of the loop finally catches up to the indexing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing that [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64020001/how-to-remove-leading-masked-elements-in-a-numpy-array#comment113208802_64020001) and [@hpaulj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64020737/2988730) suggest using a proper application of [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) instead of writing a loop yourself.

The beginning of the first `False` in each row is given by

```
start = np.argmin(m_arr.mask, axis=1)
```

Merge that with a zero in each row, and linearize the index to get some split points:

```
pad = np.zeros(m_arr.shape[0], dtype=int)
indices = np.ravel(np.stack((pad, start), axis=-1) + np.arange(m_arr.shape[0])[:, None] * m_arr.shape[1])
```

You can then split both the masked and unmasked portion of the raveled array:

```
m_arr = np.split(m_arr.ravel(), indices)[2::2]
```

**Timing**

Not especially interesting in this case, but I benchmarked a couple of calls to the following functions:

```
def foo(m):
    mm = m.mask
    mm = ~np.logical_and.accumulate(mm)
    return m[mm]

def bar_hpaulj(x):
    return [foo(m) for m in x]

def bar_MadPhysicist(x):
    return np.split(x.ravel(), (np.stack((np.zeros(x.shape[0], dtype=int), np.argmin(x.mask, axis=1)), axis=-1) + np.arange(x.shape[0])[:, None] * x.shape[1]).ravel()
)[2::2]
```

Arrays were generated as random squares for `n` in `{10, 100, 1000, 10000}`:

```
m_arr = np.ma.MaskedArray(np.ones((n, n)), mask=np.random.randint(2, size=(n, n), dtype=bool))
```

The timings are:

```
  n   |     bar_hpaulj    |  bar_MadPhysicist |
------+-------------------+-------------------+
   10 |  464 µs ± 1.54 µs |  966 µs ± 3.06 µs |
------+-------------------+-------------------+
  100 | 4.69 ms ± 20.2 µs | 8.31 ms ± 26.3 µs |
------+-------------------+-------------------+
 1000 |   67 ms ± 1.09 ms |  83.2 ms ± 309 µs |
------+-------------------+-------------------+
10000 |  2.38 s ± 29.5 ms |  835 ms ± 3.14 ms |
------+-------------------+-------------------+
```